# Automatically restart ONE single instance when CPU hits 90% on Azure App Autoscale and load balance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, devops, autoscalemode

[image: Azure Dashboard]

I've been having issues with Azure App Autoscale.
The main instance (ends with YX) always gets overloaded no matter how many other instances I add.

When the app's average CPU reaches 60%, I add one more instance.

When the average response time gets high, the app becomes unresponsive.

I am able to resolve the issue from time to time by manually restarting the primary instance.

I leave Health Check enabled, but **it never restarts the instance on its own**, as it still has the *Healthy* status.

**Is there a way to automatically restart ONE single instance when the CPU hits avg 90%?**

... or maybe another way to better allocate the resources?

Thank you.

- Graph 1: Avg CPU Percentage (all instances)
- Graph 2: Avg Response Time (all instaces)
- Graph 3: Active Instances
- Graph 4: CPU Time by Instance
- Graph 5: CPU Percentage by Instance

Comment: The problem you should be investigating is "Why does my application become unresponsive at high load?" not "How do I put a band-aid on the issue by restarting it when it becomes unresponsive?" Basically, investigate and address the root cause, not the symptom.

Comment: @DanielMann The problem is the number of requests at peak times. Why aren't new requests destined for another instance?

Comment: *The problem is the number of requests at peak times* Do the metrics tell you that? It could be *some* requests use most CPU time and it is not about the volume of the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is Azure App Service auto healing.  There are two different types that you'll want to consider.

1. [Auto Heal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics#auto-healing) allows you to set up mitigation actions based on what conditions are present in your app.  You define conditions and actions to take when those conditions are present.  There isn't a condition for CPU usage, but there are for request duration, memory limits, request counts, and status codes.  You can address your problem by setting auto-heal rules based on these other metrics.

[image]

2. The second option is [proactive auto-heal](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/17/Introducing-Proactive-Auto-Heal.html).  Proactive auto-heal will monitor your entire application and restart it if it determines that it's in a "bad state" based on memory usage and request time.

[image]

You can get to these options through your app service's "Diagnose and solve problems" blade.

[image]

It's under "diagnostic tools".

[image]